# How to sort array in to 'bins', and print out stars for how many numbers are in that bin?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bin, generate

//so basically for all that is below, I'm trying to sort the random numbers that have been generated, and then 'sort' then into bins, and then for how many numbers there are in the bin, a star * will print out for every number.  it will look like a histogram at the end. like this:

12 random integers in [0, 10) sorted into 2 bins:

******* 7 0.5833333 [5.0, 10.0)

***** 5 0.41666666 [0.0, 5.0)
but its like its skips that last two methods - generateBins, and printBins. how would i sort the random numbers into bins depending on the number (like above) and print a * for every number in that array bin?

```
public class BinSort {
    final int totalBins;
    final int totalRandom;
    final float widthBin;
    int [] storeNumbers;
    int [] binCount;

public BinSort (int nBins, int nSamples, int max) {
    totalBins = nBins; //total # of bins, ie 2
    totalRandom = nSamples; //total random number generated, ie 12
    widthBin = (float) (max/totalBins); ie 2


    int [] storeNumbers = new int [max];
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRandom-1; i++) {
storeNumbers[i] = Random.rand(i, max);
System.out.println(storeNumbers[i]);
}
}
void generateBins () {
    int [] binCount = new int [totalBins];
    for (int i=0; i < totalRandom-1; i++) {
    int bin = (int)(storeNumbers[i]/ totalBins);
    Math.floor(bin);
    bin  = binCount [i];
    }
}

void printBins () {
for (int i = 0; i < binCount.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < binCount[j]; j ++) {
           System.out.print("*");
           System.out.println(); }
    float freq = (binCount[i]/totalRandom);
    float binMin = (i * widthBin);
    float binMax = (binMin * widthBin);
    System.out.print(binCount[i] + freq + binMin + binMax);
    System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: This class doesn't skip anything -- nothing in the displayed code instantiates a `BinSort` object nor calls any methods on it. Where is the driver or test code?

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you have

```
int [] storeNumbers = new int [max];
```

The problem here is that this will create a new local variable with the same name as your instance variable, `storeNumbers`. Also, the size should be `totalRandom`, not `max`. You need to create a `Random` object that you'll use to generate random numbers. Putting this together we get:

```
public BinSort (int nBins, int nSamples, int max) {
  totalBins = nBins; //total # of bins, ie 2
  totalRandom = nSamples; //total random number generated, ie 12
  widthBin = (float) (max/totalBins); //ie 2

  storeNumbers = new int [totalRandom];
  Random rand = new Random();  
  for (int i = 0; i < totalRandom; i++) {
    storeNumbers[i] = rand.nextInt(max);
  }
}
```

This will generate `totalRandom` random numbers between `0` and `max`(exclusive) and store them the instance variable `storeNumbers`.

Next, in `generateBins` you have the same issue with

```
int [] binCount = new int [totalBins];
```

Which again will hide your instance variable `binCount`.  The bin that a `storeNumber` falls into will be given by `(int)(storeNumbers[i] / widthBin)`, and you need to increment the resulting bin by 1.

```
void generateBins()
{
  binCount = new int[totalBins];
  for (int i = 0; i < totalRandom; i++)
  {
    int bin = (int)(storeNumbers[i] / widthBin);
    binCount[bin] += 1;
  }
}
```

Finally, to the printing of the bins. This line

```
for (int j=0; j < binCount[j]; j ++)
```

should be

```
for (int j=0; j < binCount[i]; j ++)
```

Also, you should use `printf` to format the numbers you want to print.

```
void printBins()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < binCount.length; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < binCount[i]; j++)
    {
      System.out.print("*");
    }
    float freq = (float)binCount[i] / totalRandom;
    float binMin = i * widthBin;
    float binMax = (i+1) * widthBin;
    System.out.printf(" %d %.3f %.3f %.3f\n", binCount[i], freq, binMin, binMax);
  }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  BinSort bs = new BinSort(2, 12, 10);
  bs.generateBins();
  bs.printBins();
}
```

Output:

```
***** 5 0.417 0.000 5.000
******* 7 0.583 5.000 10.000
```

Which I think is what you were looking for.

Be sure to compare your original code with the changes above and make sure you understand what the issues were and why the changes work.